# Setting firebug to ignore tags and styles from extensions

Tags: firebug

is it possible to edit some settings in firebug and disable HTML tags that are added by firefox extensions (e.g. linkification or diigo) without disabling the extensions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create another profile with `firefox -ProfileManager` for your debugging. In the new profile you can install only Firebug without the other extensions you use in your standard Firefox profile.